# Empty select tag height inconsistent with the one which has a value

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have two select elements as mentioned below

```
<select size="20">
    <option>Hi</option>
    <option>2</option>
</select>
<select size="20">
</select>
```

The size of these two select elements is set to 20. Applying the below css with font-family results in shrinking of empty select element.

```
select {
            width: 200px;
            height: auto;
            font-family : 'Courier New';
        }
```

I can't give a value to height, since the select element has to display 20 items.
Is there a way to get over this issue and make it work in Firefox and Edge, other than adding a disabled/display none option to the second select element ?

```css
select {
  width: 200px;
  height: auto;
  font-family: 'Courier New';
}
```

```html
<select size="20">
  <option>Hi</option>
  <option>2</option>
</select>
<select size="20">
</select>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your question isn't clear enough. I tried your code also with firefox and it works as you describe, both select are of the same height

Comment: What's the point of having a select tag without any options?

Comment: I can reproduce this problem, but only in Chrome, seems like it works fine in firefox. Also, the different height doesn't seem to be tied to any css.

Comment: @andi I'm guessing it could potentially be empty if it's being populated from a bit of code. But still, I'd probably take the approach of hiding a select if it isn't populated with any options.

Comment: @Daniele Yes. I use ubuntu and windows 7 and its only working on ubuntu. Both the browsers are of same version though. I'm confused here.

Comment: @andi  I have other code. This is just to reproduce the issue. The actual scenario is that the first select element has few items populated and user can select them and push them to second select element; When this happens the size of first select element shrinks and second select element size increases. It kind of looks ugly when it happens.

Comment: OK, so why can't you give a value to height?  You know the height of each item (or can set it), so multiply that by 20.